# How can I index a specific word in a String in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I would like to replace all occurrences of a specific word in a Java String. For instance, I would like replace all `cat` in following string by `cat`. I have tried to implementing regex by setting pattern as `\\bcat\\b`, but it seems not working for the case when non-alphanumeric characters like underscore are around it.

`cat catabolic_cat_4cat,6cat`

How can I make a regex to exclude all non-alphanumeric characters around the word and output a sting like this:
`c*t catabolic_c*t_4cat,6cat`

Answer (score 1):

You could just alternate the word boundary character class with a class of your own making like so, and (as per Andreas' suggestion) use lookarounds to prevent catching the surrounding characters in the replace.

```
(?<=^|[^a-zA-Z0-9])cat(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9]|$)
```

Comment: You want look-ahead/-behind, otherwise the non-word character will be replaced too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, actually this one could not work

Comment: Good point Andreas I've updated my answer. @WangNick care to elaborate on what the specific issue is, or is it just the replacing of the extra characters?

Comment: This would probably be better: `(?<=^|[^a-zA-Z0-9])cat(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9]|$)`

Comment: Probably. Wasn't sure if there were any funky cases/characters I'd be missing by only including the beginning/end anchors. I suppose the not alphanumeric class pretty much handles those though.

Comment: @Andreas Actually that does!

Comment: Of course, `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` is the same as `\\P{Alnum}`, so this works too: `(?<=^|\\P{Alnum}cat(?=\\P{Alnum}|$)` --- Or, if you want full unicode support, use `(?U)(?<=^|\\P{Alnum}cat(?=\\P{Alnum}|$)` or `(?<=^|[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]cat(?=[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]|$)`

Comment: Sounds like you've got some depth on this one, might be worth posting an answer.

Answer (score -1):

How about make your code cleaner by using this inbuilt String function:

```
 String.replaceAll("oldText","newText");
```